# Combining multiple sums in one SQL query

Tags: sql, pervasive-sql

I have a database with stock, containing article numbers and changes in stock.
I want a query that will have columns article number, sum(changes 1 week ago), sum(changes 2 weeks ago), sum(changes 3 weeks ago), etc.

I have a query which can contain one sum, but how do I get multiple sums in the same query?
I tried but keep ending up with the wrong results.
Does anyone have the solution?

Queries:

```sql
SELECT Article, ROUND(SUM ("Changes" ),0) AS Usage01
FROM "Stock"
WHERE "Date" BETWEEN (REPLACE ((CONVERT ((CURDATE ()-14),SQL_CHAR )),'-' ,'' ))AND (REPLACE ((CONVERT ((CURDATE ()-8),SQL_CHAR )),'-' ,'' )) 
GROUP BY "Stock" ."Article" 
ORDER BY "Stock" ."Article"
```

```sql
SELECT Article, ROUND(SUM ("Changes" ),0) AS Usage02
FROM "Stock"
WHERE "Date" BETWEEN (REPLACE ((CONVERT ((CURDATE ()-21),SQL_CHAR )),'-' ,'' ))AND (REPLACE ((CONVERT ((CURDATE ()-15),SQL_CHAR )),'-' ,'' )) 
GROUP BY "Stock" ."Article"
ORDER BY "Stock" ."Article"
```

```sql
SELECT Article, ROUND(SUM ("Changes" ),0) AS Usage03
FROM "Stock"
WHERE "Date" BETWEEN (REPLACE ((CONVERT ((CURDATE ()-28),SQL_CHAR )),'-' ,'' ))AND (REPLACE ((CONVERT ((CURDATE ()-22),SQL_CHAR )),'-' ,'' )) 
GROUP BY "Stock" ."Article"
ORDER BY "Stock" ."Article"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ARTICLE,
 SUM
  (
     CASE 
      WHEN DATE BETWEEN FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK AND LAST_DAY_OF WEEK THEN CHANGES
      ELSE NULL
     END
  )AS WEEK,
 SUM
  (
     CASE 
       WHEN DATE BETWEEN FIRST_DAY_OF_PREVIOUS_WEEK AND LAST_DAY_OF_PREVIOUS_WEEK THEN CHANGES
       ELSE NULL
     END
   )AS WEEK_PREVIOUS
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
  GROUP BY ARTICLE
```

I guess you can use "conditional aggregation". I am sorry I haven't ever seen pervasive-sql, so can not write the query, but idea looks like in the above query

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
SELECT Article, 
    ROUND(SUM (CASE WHEN "Date" BETWEEN (REPLACE ((CONVERT ((CURDATE () - 14), SQL_CHAR )), '-' , '' )) AND (REPLACE ((CONVERT ((CURDATE () - 8), SQL_CHAR )), '-' , '' )) THEN "Changes" END ), 0) AS Usage01,
    ROUND(SUM (CASE WHEN "Date" BETWEEN (REPLACE ((CONVERT ((CURDATE () - 21), SQL_CHAR )), '-' , '' )) AND (REPLACE ((CONVERT ((CURDATE () - 15), SQL_CHAR )), '-' , '' ))  THEN "Changes" END ), 0) AS Usage02, 
    ROUND(SUM (CASE WHEN "Date" BETWEEN (REPLACE ((CONVERT ((CURDATE () - 28), SQL_CHAR )), '-' , '' )) AND (REPLACE ((CONVERT ((CURDATE () - 22), SQL_CHAR )), '-' , '' ))  THEN "Changes" END ), 0) AS Usage03
FROM "Stock" s
GROUP BY s."Article" 
ORDER BY s."Article";
```